# postgresql-crunchy not in rhc port-forward list

Tags: postgresql, openshift, portforwarding, openshift-client-tools

I have installed Postgresql 9.3 on OpenShift with the cartridge available at [github](https://github.com/crunchyds/openshift-postgres-cartridge). The database is started.

I want to connect to it from PgAdmin-III on my local PC. I am supposed to forward ports with:

```
rhc port-forward <myapp>
```

Yet, the list of port forwarding does not contain a forwarding for my Postgresql database. Hence, I cannot configure PgAdmin-III with the local port used for forwarding.

```
C:\>rhc port-forward ligatures
Checking available ports ... done
Forwarding ports ...
Permission denied - bind(2) while forwarding port 8080. Trying local port 8081
Permission denied - bind(2) while forwarding port 8080. Trying local port 8081
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
normally permitted. - bind(2) while forwarding port 8081. Trying local port 8082

Permission denied - bind(2) while forwarding port 8080. Trying local port 8081
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
normally permitted. - bind(2) while forwarding port 8081. Trying local port 8082

Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
normally permitted. - bind(2) while forwarding port 8082. Trying local port 8083


To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address

Service Local               OpenShift
------- -------------- ---- -----------------
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8081  =>  127.2.56.130:8080
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8082  =>  127.2.56.131:8080
node    127.0.0.1:8083  =>  127.2.56.129:8080

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

How do I get a port forwarding for my postgresql-crunchy database?

**Update**

I have opened an [issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1190232) at Bugzilla Redhat.

**Update II**

Issue can be replicated by creating a simple scalable nodejs + crunchydb application at Openshift.

Comment: Why the -1? Can you please explain?

Comment: Why did you open an issue with Red Hat? This is a third party cartridge that was not designed or developed by Red Hat.

Comment: I have opened that issue a couple of hours ago, before I got your answer. I have just added a note about your answer. I am also sending an email to a contact at Crunchy Data Solution. I guess they will close it if this is not on their side.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the manifest.yml file, it does not look like it is publishing it's list of ports correctly (https://github.com/CrunchyData/openshift-postgres-cartridge/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml) under the "Publishes" section, which is missing, take a look at this manifest for the official postgresql cartridge and compare the Publishes sections (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-postgresql/metadata/manifest.yml)

It also seems to be missing the "protocols" section, along with other important information.

It should also probably use more descriptive port names in the "Endpoints" section.  I would recommend logging an issue on that github repo with the specifics of the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the cartridge just now without any problems.  I'll take this offline with the user and try to resolve the problem.